# Unity - Code not compiled after deletion of scriptable object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a unity project that unfortunately doesn't compile anymore since I deleted a scriptable object.

I originally tried to modify the SO but so no impact on the relying objects, so I got a little impatient and deleted the whole thing (and the depending objects) thinking I would be able to recreate it afterwards. Nonetheless it didn't work, and even after creating the new SO and trying to run it, my code doesn't compile.

Unity returns the message indicating that compiling errors needs to be fixed before playing, but I see nothing in the editor.

I am fairly new to unity and programming in general, and probably did something I was not supposed to. But would you have an idea o how to save the situation? I found no trace of such a problem elsewhere and is at my wits end right now.

Comment: I'm sure you are getting some sort of error, can you post what those errors are? Make sure you look at your console window and enable errors.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. The unity console is enabled but doesn't bring any issue (which seems logical to me as at that point the code doesn't even seem to execute). The visual studio error list is also desperately empty as there is no error or warning in there either.